# loading a program in another sector at emu8086

Tags: assembly, x86

I used micro_os_loader and I made my own kernel and it works just fine. Kernel must be at sector 2 it is ok I did it in that way but I want to write a program in sector 4 and want to run it in kernel as a sub-program. but how can I do that? In kernel what should I do to make my program run in sector 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pretty much depends on how your kernel works.

You need to read the program code into memory, create a process for it and... well... the next step is already pretty much design-dependent.

Basically you need to have CS:IP to point to the entry point of the program.

For example, if you're multitasking, you probably set up the timer interrupt with a handler that saves all the registers in the PCB and picks another process from the process queue. Then it loads the registers from the PCB belonging to that process, tampers the return address on the stack to point to the next instruction to execute from that process and the issues *iret* to give the process control.

Meanwhile, the kernel is idling in a loop - example:

```
idle:
    hlt
    jmp idle
```

From here, the kernel does not have any linear work to do. Instead it sits idle awaiting system calls from processes and interrupts from hardware to handle. System calls are usually implemented in the form of interrupt handler(s), so all kinds of asynchronous events that occur in a system can be dealt with in a uniform way.

[EDIT]

For the additional example, we'll go with preemptive multitasking, foolishly hardcoding the scheduler into the timer IRQ handler and without going into all the details. For example, implementing the process queue is up to you (it's just a list of PCBs somewhere in memory). We won't reprogram the timer as it is not essential (it is already running and generating IRQ 0's). You may however reprogram it as you like so you can switch tasks at a rate other than that provided by the default 8253/8254 setup.
Also, please note that IRL you need to save the FPU state and some other stuff too...

```
; cdecl calling convention
; ugly pieces of code appear! DO NOT COPY-PASTE OR OTHERWISE USE THIS! this is just for illustration


proc timerInterruptHandler
    cli                     ; disabling interrupts so they don't mess up anything. no need to worry about re-enabling them as FLAGS is implicitly saved on the stack
    push ax                 ; let's first save our current CPU state on the stack
    push cx
    push dx
    push bx
    push bp
    push sp
    push si
    push di
    push es
    push ss
    push ds

    push bp
    mov bp,sp

    call getCurrentProcess    ; get the current process instance. let's now assume that the context is simply saved at relative address 0
    mov di,ax
    lea si,[bp + 2]
    mov cx,14
    rep movsw                 ; save the contents of each register to the buffer

    call selectNextProcess    ; we'll select the next process from the queue (or the first when the current is the last one).
    mov si,ax
    lea di,[bp + 2]
    mov cx,14
    rep movsw                 ; overwrite the saved registers on the stack with the saved state of our new process
                              ; upon returning from the handler (the next steps), the state of the new process will be loaded

    mov sp,bp
    pop bp

    pop ds
    pop ss
    pop es
    pop di
    pop si
    pop sp
    pop bp
    pop bx
    pop dx
    pop cx
    call acknowledgeMasterPICInterrupt  ; every IRQ must be acknowledged to the corresponding PIC (both if the IRQ is triggered by the salve PIC, i.e. IRQ8+)
    pop ax
    iret
endp timerInterruptHandler


; void setUpTaskScheduler(void)
proc setUpTaskScheduler                ; here we assume that no IRQ remapping is done, thus IRQ 0 (timer) is at INT 8.
    pushf
    cli
    push bx
    push ds

    mov cx,2                           ; multiplying the interrupt number by 4 gives you the address of the IVT record to modify
    mov bx,8
    shl bx,cx

    xor ax,ax
    mov ds,ax

    lea ax,[cs:timerInterruptHandler]   ; write the offset first
    mov [word ptr ds:bx + 0],ax
    mov ax,cs
    mov [word ptr ds:bx + 2],ax         ; then the segment


    pop ds
    pop bx
    popf
    ret
endp setUpTaskScheduler


; void acknowledgeMasterPICInterrupt(void)
proc acknowledgeMasterPICInterrupt
    mov al,20h
    out 20h,al
    ret
endp acknowledgeMasterPICInterrupt


; void acknowledgeSlavePICInterrupt(void)
proc acknowledgeSlavePICInterrupt
    mov al,20h
    out 0A0h,al
    call acknowledgeMasterPICInterrupt
    ret
endp acknowledgeSlavePICInterrupt

_main:
    ; ...
    call setUpTaskScheduler
    ; Once interrupts are enabled the scheduler will start doing its work
    ; ...
```

[/EDIT]

**[Here](http://wiki.osdev.org/Programmable_Interval_Timer)** you can find code examples that reprogram the PIT.

Comment: thanks for your answer it helped very well. ı saved all registers and when ı back ı loaded them back now it works pretty fine. again thank you very much

Comment: @Alparslanyk You're welcome! :) Pay attention on literally saving everything (e.g. general regs, segments, flags, 8087 registers if used) so that programs (and kernel) running separately do not interfere with each other. Should anything go wrong, feel free to throw a question at me.

Comment: @Alparslanyk I see you've unaccepted the solution. What went wrong?

Comment: soryy dude ı am totaly newbee at here ı accept it now and thx you very much ı works fine [:

Comment: @Alparslanyk No worries :) I was just wondering if anything arose to be solved yet...

Comment: ı need your help one mor time pal.

Comment: I have a homework about multitasking in emu8086. I have my kernel and some programs which runs pretty good in sperate but how do ı make them in multitasking. I have no idea.Teacher said me you can use timer interrupt or a comman counter or double stack but ı have no idea what to do. Can youhelp me? any example or nay information about it. ı have no idea what to do pal. and thank you again for your interest [:

Comment: Just as I described above :) You set up the interrupt handler so that it saves registers (and stuff) and then picks another process from the queue, tampers return address then issues `iret`. [The 8254 timer can be reprogrammed](http://www.brokenthorn.com/Resources/OSDevPit.html) so that it keeps firing IRQ0 at a desired interval (100Hz is common). Well, actually the interrupt handler should just call the process scheduler - also, system calls may call the scheduler so while one process is blocked for I/O, another can run

Comment: Dude you told it good but ı am really newbie at this [: and using emu8086 for this homework not a real processor [: can you tell me a little bit detail or a example how to use this timer [:

Comment: The [Intel 8253/8254 chip info](http://wiki.osdev.org/Programmable_Interval_Timer) and referenced documents should be informative enough to get you on the track. If emu8086 is accurate enough, I guess it matches an IBM PC clone (with i8086) so it doesn't matter whether you have a physical box or the emulator. These 2 links (the above one along with the other one in my previous comment) describe the use of the *8253/8254*.

Comment: Set up the interrupt vector at **[0000h:0020h]** to point at your handler. Your handler should disable interrupts (no need to worry about re-enabling them as *flags* is stored on the stack), and call the *task scheduler*. The scheduler in turn should save all the registers and `flags`/`cs`/`ip` from the stack (you could pass them as arguments from the handler), load the new register values from the PCB of the next task to run. Then overwrite `flags`/`cs`/`ip` on  the stack and voilá: The interrupt handler will return to the new task instead of the original one.

Comment: If you'd still like to see an example, please let me know and I'll edit my answer.

Comment: thank you pal. your answer is truelly informative ı will look your link but if it is possible ı would like to see and writen example if it  is not to much trouble [:

Comment: @Alparslanyk 'kay, lemme wake up and get to the (no, not the choppa) office. Then I'll gladly present some stuff.

Comment: aw, sorry, mate, I had plenty of stuff to do at work. I'll get back to you as soon as I have some time...

Comment: no worries, I just couldn't come back and show some code. Now I'm gonna drink my coffee and give it a try...

Comment: There ya go :) I've added some basic task switching example. The handler saves the CPU state (i.e. the registers), switches to another tasks' saved state, overwrites the stack contents from where the CPU state is loaded, loads the registers that need to be loaded explicitly, notifies the *interrupt controller* that it has finished its work and then returns (to the newly loaded process). I hope it's clear enough

Comment: Thank you very much pal. ı am really happy for your help. you wroked for my problem and make it works thanks alot dude [:ı am gonna check it out your link and learn in deep of this assembly ı hope after all thank you again [:

Comment: dude ı have your answer and maded my homewrok works thank you very much. I know ı wanted so much thing from you but if you are avaible please can you check my new question on this page please. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16325881/displaying-or-editing-data-readed-from-floppy

Comment: Ah, sorry, I've just read your message and I'm done for today at the office. Tomorrow I'll get back to check it. Cheers!

Comment: 'ey there! I think we'd have to put this issue off till next week. I owe the guys a missing Service and we have some freaking ugly spaghetti code to overcome so we can establish a demo on Monday. Terribly sorry about that. Maybe someone else gives you the answer meanwhile...

Comment: dude ofcourse this is not a priority of your job. please it is totally fine for me you have helped me very enough [:

Comment: I have to admit I had some difficulties understanding the question, but I tried my best to give useful help. Good luck!