# Displaying or editing data readed from floppy

Tags: assembly

Hi guys ı have question and hope to you help me about it. I have a homework about making a simple fat system for my os. ı have my code at the end. ı am writing some string on my floopy_0 and ı am reading it but how can ı edit or making something on it? ı have no idea. ı must read my fat system in my floppy after ı read ı must decripted it. So ı must access my readed fat file on floopy ot make compare or display on screen. 
how it works: 
in table label ı have my cripted data and first 7 byte is my program names,
 8 is its kind- can be 0 or 1(asm or txt) 
9-10(clinder number) 
11-12 (sector number)
 13 (head number) 
and 14-15 is size(how many sector it has). For example:

```
table db "apple  0001002", 0Dh,0Ah 
  db "orange 0010102", 0Dh,0Ah 
  db "clean  0020502", 0Dh,0Ah 
  db "story  0001502", 0
```

this is what ı am writing on my clinder 1 sector 1 and head 0(where is my fat). I must read clinder sector and head number from readed file to read program which typed in my kernel
here is my question:
 "How could ı use this to display on screan and what can ı do to make the program selected?
For example: when teacher write "apple" in my kernel. it must start apple program. ı have program and ı can run it but ı have no idea what to do for after ı read my fat and to compare"apple" in my program list. ı can run it if it is in my list but how can check it is in my list???

Biggest deal is **I MUST READ MY FAT FROM MY FLOOPY AND I MUST CHECK NAMES WHİCH TEACHER GİVE ME İN READED FAT FİLE?** Please help me how can ı do this?

Comment: Is it a 5 1/4 or 8 1/2 inch floppy? ;) - seriously, though, post what you have so far.

Comment: You appear to put the {type,c,s,h} inside the string tobether with the name := `"orange 0010102"` is that intentional, or should it be a 7-char string plus 4 (binary) bytes. The "\r\n" at the end of the records neither makes any sense to me.

Comment: man what can ı use as ı am asking like a noob question? ı am using emu8086 and using its floppy. and for \r\n dude ı am tryting to put a table in floppy it is in this way because when ı read from this file from disk, ı wanna read as ı writed. and yes "orange 0010102" in intentional. ı explaned what it means in my question. I am asking just this how could ı reach the data ı readed from disk to use it display on screen or to make it decripted? this is what all about ı am asking. with my best compliments and thanks

Answer (score 0):

Editing files is about reading their contents into memory, altering their contents in-memory and writing them back to the disk.

For example, upon receiving an `openFile` system call from one of the user applications, you load the file, record that it is in use by an application (so no other app can use it at the same time), create a file info block containing data like some resource identifier (e.g. file path), whether it is open for *read*, *write* or *append*, a *file pointer* holding the memory address that is currently to be accessed inside the file (e.g. 0 initially and grows upwards with read/write operations), the size of the file, and the address of the beginning of the file in memory. Also, a flag indicating whether the contents have been modified or not can be useful. Once it's done, you return the address of the file info data structure to the user application.

The application in turn can then invoke, passing the pointer back along with other necessary parameters, `readFile` for reading a given number of consecutive bytes from the file, `writeFile` for writing a given number of bytes from a buffer to the file, `seekFile` to set the *file pointer* to a given offset into the file (the *N*th byte in the file buffer, i.e. the base address of the file in memory + *N*), and `closeFile` with the handle (the address of the info block) alone to write back changes from memory to disk and release the file so that other processes can use it.

There are of course way more sophisticated approaches than this, but this simple thing works just fine for small systems.

---

Displaying the data is a different story and is the responsibility of another module (actually not even a single module, but a few of them). Here, things are revolving around the 80x25 character screen, layed out as continuous memory area from 0xB8000 (0B800h:0000), each character having two bytes: the first for the ASCII character code itself and the second for meta attributes like background color, foreground color, and blinking. Character colors are specified with 4 bits, the highest bit being the *'light- flag'* the remaining bits being for RGB respectively (e.g. 1100b or 0Ch is light red). The upper nibble controls the background color, but the highest bit, rather than being the *'light- flag'*, is the *blinking* flag and for BG you're restricted to 8 colors.

Remember that you as the kernel are not the one who displays the file data. It's not your responsibility to decide what to do with the data that's read from the file.
It's the user application who may invoke your, say, `writeLine` system call for displaying any string - which may as well be the very file data it requested from you a moment ago.

---

Slightly off topic, but belongs to the previous paragraph is the fact the the **shell** that users type commands into (or click on windows and buttons of which) is just a regular user application that utilizes operating system features as per user request.

Comment: dude main question is that table db "apple  0001002", 0Dh,0Ah 
  db "orange 0010102", 0Dh,0Ah 
  db "clean  0020502", 0Dh,0Ah 
  db "story  0001502", 0  ı got this table and ı write it on sector 1 clinder 1 and head 0 that is ok. but how can ı read it to use for something. that is the main. after ı read same sector and clinder how ı use this file for example how can ı check 8th bit of my tables fisrt word("apple  0001002") but for cheacking ı must read file from disk and after that ı must look what ı am looking for.

Comment: Read it with `int 13h` or direct disk I/O. For the former I recommend googling "Ralph Brown's Interrupt List" or taking a look **[here](http://wiki.osdev.org/ATA_in_x86_RealMode_%28BIOS%29)**, for the second... Well, try **[this one](http://wiki.osdev.org/ATA_PIO_Mode)**. *Keep an eye on 8086 compatibility!!! (e.g. LBA is unlikely to work)* After you read it into memory, you can access it. To check the 8th bit of "apple" you load the first word (offset 0) from the buffer into `ax`, `test ax,256` and if `ZF` is 0, the bit in question is set.

Comment: If you want to use FAT, then there's more to this, but I think you can already find the osdev wik, I really recommend reading that. There you can find information about filesystems too. Things remain quite much the same except for adding a filesystem layer between the disk I/O and the code requesting loading of the data. 1) You load your data into the buffer. 2) You read/write the buffer. 3) If you've made any changes, you write them back to the disk.

Comment: thank you pal that was very usefull. ı will read that wiki and at last ı hope ı will figüre out how ı can load words to ax :D actually that was my question but ı couldnt be so clear sorry for that and for my english [:

Comment: By *word* I meant a two-byte value. :) Loading them into a register is what stuff like `mov ax,[word ptr ds:whatever]` is for. Also, you can have the very useful `lods`, `stos`, `movs` and `scas`, `cmps` instruction family for string operations. Suppose you've loaded your file at address `1000h:0000h`. You can then set `es` to 1000h, `xor si,si` and use `es:lodsb` to load individual bytes into the `al` register one-by-one so you can process your string whatever way you want.